# Send json from Stream analytics to Power Bi

Tags: arrays, json, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, streamanalytix

[image]I am trying to send simulated data from kepware to azure Hub and then to Stream analytic. Next step would be directly to Power Bi but it seems like stream analytics is sending an array to Power Bi.
here is my data from kepware:

[image]

```
SELECT 
   event.[values].id as id,
   event.[values].v as Measurements,
   event.[values].t as Time,
   event.[values].q as Quality

   INTO PowerBiVisualizationOutput
   FROM PowerBiVisualizationInput AS event
   CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.[values]) AS sensordata
```

I have tried so many different way of writing quarries but they all are giving me null in output. Can some one please help me

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for using [GetArrayElements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/getarrayelements-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) is illustrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json#convert-array-elements-into-separate-events).

Note how it returns a record/object for each item/row of your array, that in your case you named `sensordata` (it's not `event.` anymore). That record has 2 properties : **ArrayIndex** and **ArrayValue**, that are hardcoded (part of GetArrayElements). Here you want to grab your properties out of **ArrayValue**:

```
SELECT 
   sensordata.ArrayValue.id as id,
   sensordata.ArrayValue.v as Measurements,
   sensordata.ArrayValue.t as Time,
   sensordata.ArrayValue.q as Quality

   INTO PowerBiVisualizationOutput
   FROM PowerBiVisualizationInput AS event
   CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.[values]) AS sensordata
```

*Edit following our conversation in comments:*
Looking at the first screenshot, the field name we're trying to unfold is `[value]` and not `value`, the square brackets `[]` are in there.

To reference such fields in a query, we can use double quotes: `"[value]"`:

```
SELECT 
   sensordata.ArrayValue.id as id,
   sensordata.ArrayValue.v as Measurements,
   sensordata.ArrayValue.t as Time,
   sensordata.ArrayValue.q as Quality

   INTO PowerBiVisualizationOutput
   FROM PowerBiVisualizationInput AS event
   CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements("[values]") AS sensordata
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Florian but it still gives me Null rows :(

Comment: here is the Test Result: Showing 0 rows from 'PowerBiVisualizationOutput'.

Comment: Could you please add the result of a SELECT * in your question? Also you can share a sample file, that would help.

Comment: Here is the result for SELECT* :
Showing 50 rows from 'PowerBiVisualizationOutput'.
timestamp    1633067847169
[values]          [{"id":"Channel1.Machine1.Pres","v":777,"q":1,"t":1633067842285},{"id":"Channel1.Machine1.Hum","v":49,"q":1,"t":1633067842285},{"id":"Channel1.Machine1.Temp","v":227,"q":1,"t":1633067842285}]

EventProcessedUtcTime    "2021-10-01T06:49:22.7379244Z"
PartitionId    1
EventEnqueuedUtcTime "2021-10-01T05:57:27.1860000Z

Comment: Sorry Florian I don't know how to add image here. I get my data from Kepware and I dont have a file for the result

Comment: I have downloaded the test result from azure but can I send it to your mail?

Comment: You can certainly do at askasa@microsoft.com

Comment: Could you please try the following : SELECT S.* INTO TestOutput FROM PowerBiVisualizationInput P CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(P.Values) AS S

Comment: Hi Florian
It still gives me Null

Comment: I have sent you an email with the sample data. Thanks for your help